# removing special codes using asp and RegExp

Tags: regex, asp-classic

Hi im just wondering if anyone knows how to remove special codes and spaces from a string in asp classic ?

thanks

Comment: Simple version is "iterate through the string, appending those chars not filtered out to a variable". Your tags suggest you want to know about the regex approach, which has different pros and cons, but to answer we'd have to know what you mean by "special".

Comment: Hi well specials codes like the © and ™

Comment: What's special about them? Do you mean anything not alphanumeric, anything not alphanumeric and also not ASCII? There's no such thing as "special" except for your requirements making them so, so without knowing your requirements we're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

don't know asp but just pass in a replace for everything that is not [^0-9a-fA-F]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove a character from a string using the REPLACE function http://devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/13958.asp

You can implement Regular Expression to search the strings with the REGEXP OBJECT http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/14108.asp

Answer (score 0):

@Jay: If you don't want to go the regular expression route, this could work for you:

```
<%
Option Explicit

Function alphanum(ByVal sText)
    Dim sChr, i

    If NOT IsNumeric(sText) Then
        For i = 1 To Len(sText)
            sChr = Mid(sText, i, 1)

            If IsNumeric(sChr) Then
                alphanum = alphanum & sChr
            Else
                If sChr = " " OR (Asc(LCase(sChr)) <= 122 AND Asc(LCase(sChr)) >= 97) Then
                    alphanum = alphanum & sChr
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Else
        alphanum = sText
    End If
End Function


Dim sInput

sInput = alphanum("$%^ (O_oh)")
sInput = Replace(sInput, " ", "") 

Response.Write sInput
%>
```